# Mongodb replica set - always shows "syncingTo"

Tags: mongodb

I have a 3 member replica set, Mongo version 3.0.8. It is running on Linux instances on AWS-EC2. Here is the rs.status() output:

```
rs.status()
{
        "set" : "s-1",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-05-04T20:52:26.279Z"),
        "myState" : 2,
        "syncingTo" : "MongoA:27017",
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "MongoB:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 14809,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1462382654, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-05-04T17:24:14Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-05-04T20:52:25.620Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-05-04T20:52:25.635Z"                     ),
                        "pingMs" : 0,
                        "syncingTo" : "MongoC:27017",
                        "configVersion" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "MongoA:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 14852,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1462382654, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-05-04T17:24:14Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-05-04T20:52:24.506Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-05-04T20:52:24.493Z"                     ),
                        "pingMs" : 9,
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1462380294, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-05-04T16:44:54Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "MongoC:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 89095,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1462382654, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-05-04T17:24:14Z"),
                        "syncingTo" : "MongoA:27017",
                        "configVersion" : 1,
                        "self" : true
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I connect to Mongo via command line from a separate (test) server (not one of the Mongo instances) using this command:

```
mongo --host MongoA:27017,MongoB:27017,MongoC:27017
```

I have my AWS security group set up such that all members of the replica set are members of the security group, and that port 27017 is open to all of the replica set members as well as to my test server.

Whenever I connect via command line, I always get connected to a SECONDARY server (never the PRIMARY). From what I've read, this is related to the fact that the replica set is still 'syncing'.

My question is why is it always in the syncing state? Is there something preventing the set members from syncing (such as access to a particular port or something)?

Any help or suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is why is it always in the syncing state? Is there something preventing the set members from syncing (such as access to a particular port or something)?

The [`syncingTo`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/#replSetGetStatus.members[n].syncingTo) field is informational: it indicates where a secondary is currently pulling oplog updates from for replication. This can either be the current primary, or another secondary with [chained replication](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-chained-replication/) (generally only seen with geographically distributed replica sets).

The presence of this field is unrelated to the current [replica set member state](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-states/) which would be `STARTUP2` if initial sync is still completing or `SECONDARY` if a member is in a normal state.

The `syncingTo` field would be more appropriately renamed to `syncingFrom`, but the historical naming choice has been in place since MongoDB 2.2 and renaming will break existing scripts/tools. You may want to watch/upvote [SERVER-5461](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5461); it's possible this field will be renamed in a future major release.

> Whenever I connect via command line, I always get connected to a SECONDARY server (never the PRIMARY). From what I've read, this is related to the fact that the replica set is still 'syncing'.

The issue is with your connection string:

```
mongo --host MongoA:27017,MongoB:27017,MongoC:27017
```

For a [replica set connection](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption--host) with the MongoDB 3.0 shell you need to include the `replSet` name before the seed list (which looks like `s-1` per your `rs.status()` output):

```
mongo --host s-1/MongoA:27017,MongoB:27017,MongoC:27017
```

Without the replSet prefix in your connection string, you will always be connecting to the first host in the list which happens to currently be a secondary as per your `rs.status()` output. If you use the correct format you will be connected to the current primary as long as at least one of the hosts in your seed list is available (and there is a primary).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation. Since I've always used the same connection string (without the replSet) I guess I've just been fortunate to connect to the PRIMARY.